# filtering each column of a data frame an put NA for unmatched values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a table as follows:

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3]    [,4]   [,5] 
[1,]  a     A   0.06    0.31   -1.5
[2,]  b     B  -0.75    0.2    0.02
[3,]  c     C   1.58   -0.02    1.5
```

I would like to put a cutoff on column 3 to 5 to find the cells that their absolute value are greater than 1.

I also would like to fill the matching values with the absolute value and the  cells that do not match the criteria with "NA".

To do so I am using filter function from dplyr package but I can not get the desired result. Does any one have idea How can I do this.

here is what the output must look:

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3]    [,4]   [,5] 
[1,]  a     A   NA       NA    1.5
[2,]  b     B   NA       NA     NA
[3,]  c     C   1.58     NA    1.5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can try using `dplyr::mutate_at` as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(3:5), funs(ifelse(abs(.) > 1, abs(.), NA_integer_)))
```

OR  If data has `factor` type columns try as:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(3:5), funs(ifelse(abs(as.numeric(as.character(.))) > 1, 
                                     abs(as.numeric(as.character(.))), NA_integer_)))

#   V1 V2   V3 V4  V5
# 1  a  A   NA NA 1.5
# 2  b  B   NA NA  NA
# 3  c  C 1.58 NA 1.5
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
a     A   0.06    0.31   -1.5
b     B  -0.75    0.2    0.02
c     C   1.58   -0.02    1.5",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: When I try your code I get this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: ‘abs’ not meaningful for factors. I tried to convert factors to numeric with following code:  df <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(df[3:5]))) . But I still all the values are replaced with "NAs". I guess if I convert factors to numeric successfully I can use your code. Do you know how can I avoid NAs?

Comment: @yas.f Seems your data got few columns as `factor`. If so please try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using only R base functions like this:

```
> dat <- read.table(text="a     A   0.06    0.31   -1.5
 b     B  -0.75    0.2    0.02
 c     C   1.58   -0.02    1.5", header=FALSE)
> dat[,3:5][abs(dat[,3:5])<=1]<-NA
> dat[,3:5] <- abs(dat[,3:5])
> dat
  V1 V2   V3 V4  V5
1  a  A   NA NA 1.5
2  b  B   NA NA  NA
3  c  C 1.58 NA 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code but it give me the following error: non-numeric variable in data frame: I used as.numeric function But I got this error: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, abs(as.numeric(dat[, 3:5])) <= 1, value = NA) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @JilberUrbina I think you have to use 2-step process. First replace cells with `abs` value less than `1` to `NA`. And then replace rest with `abs` value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
df[3:5] <- lapply(df[3:5], function(x) replace(x, abs(x) < 1, NA))
df
#  V1 V2   V3 V4   V5
#1  a  A   NA NA -1.5
#2  b  B   NA NA   NA
#3  c  C 1.58 NA  1.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "b", "c"), V2 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
V3 = c(0.06, -0.75, 1.58), V4 = c(0.31, 0.2, -0.02), V5 = c(-1.5, 
0.02, 1.5)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat <- read.table(text="
        a     A   0.06    0.31   -1.5
        b     B  -0.75    0.2    0.02
        c     C   1.58   -0.02    1.5", header=FALSE)

 dat[3:5] = abs(dat[3:5])

 is.na(dat[3:5]) = dat[3:5]<1

 dat
  V1 V2   V3 V4  V5
1  a  A   NA NA 1.5
2  b  B   NA NA  NA
3  c  C 1.58 NA 1.5
```